# Reach out to Travis-CI about outsourcing their support to Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, outsourcing

As previously noted in one of the comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29305116/4200092), the "Ask a Question" link on the [Travis CI website](https://travis-ci.org/) simply redirects to the Stack Overflow "Ask" page, with the [travis-ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/travis-ci) tag added automatically. I flagged that post as off-topic, and it was closed by [Brad Larson ♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) shortly afterwards.

However, I'm wondering if there has been any discussion with the Travis CI folks about them clarifying what is/is not [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here before sending users over here?

**EDIT:** Here's a copy of the question linked to above, in case it disappears later:

> ### any plans to offer maven 3.3.1 on travis-ci?
>
> I'd love to use the new support for extensions in maven 3.3.1
>
> cf.
>   http://blog.soebes.de/blog/2015/03/17/apache-maven-3-dot-3-1-features/

Comment: Help link that only sends them to Stack Overflow's "Ask" page is definitely not a good thing.  General advice:  see a poorly written question, downvote it.  If it's off-topic, close it.  No one cares where it came from ultimately.

Comment: We did talk about this internally among moderators at the time I saw that question. However, I went back through a recent history of questions in that tag and found very few that were terrible or completely off topic. The tag seemed to be doing far better than many other cases where people had directed their support here, so it didn't seem that urgent to talk to them about this. It helps that the only people who would be using this tool are programmers.

Comment: @BradLarson Thanks for taking the time to reply. To be honest, what you say pretty closely matches what I was thinking (tagged questions generally good, tool mainly used by programmers, etc.) but I was curious enough to ask about the "official" opinion here on Meta. :)

Comment: Google does this as well with their Gmail API: https://developers.google.com/gmail/

Comment: At least Google explicitly stated it'll be on Stack Overflow.

Comment: What about permanently preventing this abuse of linking directly to the Ask Question page ? If the referer header isn't SE, then show an additional warning page containing [something like this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746/2629998).

Comment: @Ryan In my eyes, there's a huge difference between linking to your company's tag and linking to the ask page.

Comment: I've just encountered this [on this particular question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31416186/1079354).  I really would feel better if someone did reach out to them.  Regardless of how active they may be in those tags, having their "Ask a Question" link point *directly* to a new Stack Overflow question is disquieting.