# Square is using SO as their "tech support forum" - lots of off-topic questions as a result

Tags: discussion, outsourcing

After reading a suggestion to bring something like this up from [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256090/1188035), I've decided to make a question here about how to best approach a problem I've run into with one recently posted question that helped me discover a problematic trend from one company.

The user asked a [fairly broad question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30036141/commissionable-sales). I found that the other two questions he's posted were well-explained and on-topic, so I've given them the upvotes they deserved, but still decided to downvote/vote to close this particular one. The user [didn't take it so well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30036141/commissionable-sales#comment48189182_30036141), and after a few more comments, he [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30036141/commissionable-sales#comment48191162_30036141) that [Square is using SO as their official support channel](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/#implementationquestions).

I [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30036141/commissionable-sales#comment48191696_30036141) that having a company direct you to SO doesn't create an exemption from the rules and referenced [these](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company) [two](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256088/do-any-companies-have-agreements-with-stack-overflow-to-use-the-site-as-a-suppor) quite popular meta posts concerning the matter. There's nothing more else I can do there, but I did take a look into [the `square-connect` tag he was using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/square-connect) and found a fair quantity of zero-vote or negative-voted questions of an off-topic nature.

I did notice that [one user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3233717/stephen-barlow) was consistently answering these questions, and appears to be employed by Square. The answers he posted weren't really answers, but [full of helpdesk language](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30037144/1188035) (e.g. "we do/do not support this feature").

What's worse, the [only question from the tag that actually received upvotes for being a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27951035/debugging-register-error) didn't appear to receive help or answers from SO. (There may be a deleted set of comments that I'm not seeing)

Should/can someone talk to Square about this? Am I being crazy in thinking the one question I voted to close is too broad? Should I do something about all of these other questions (e.g. vote to close the rest of the ones that are too broad)?

Since Square seems to have dedicated an employee to checking up on questions with this tag, why can't we give these sort of vendors moderation abilities specifically for a tag (along with a mandatory walkthrough on moderation of questions) so the community doesn't have to deal with the mess that comes from sending their users here?

Comment: I think this boils down to: Is asking how to use a specific api to get a desired result on topic for stackoverflow. and, i'm unsure. The fact that it's about the square-connect is irrelevant i think.

Comment: Did he indicate where he came from? Having a bit of trouble seeing where Square is referencing SO here...

Comment: @Shog9 https://docs.connect.squareup.com/#implementationquestions

Comment: Hard to see how a [square-connect] api expert could not answer that question.  The OP also tagged the question properly and did not add the [kitchen-sink].  Consider adding the tag to your "Ignored Tags" section in your profile so you don't have to look at them anymore.

Comment: @HansPassant - so your suggestion is just ignore it and it'll go away?

Comment: @HansPassant How could a Square expert answer that question? I read the docs, I saw that it doesn't have "commissions" as a native feature, so obviously the asker would have to build it. Would the "Square expert" tell them how to build something using their API, step by step?

Comment: @KevinB Thanks so much, I've added your link to my question. I think it kind of boils down to what you're saying. I think that SO takes a very muddy stance on vendor API support, and that they should provide vendors with a more structured means of sending users here.

Comment: @sjagr they very well could. I look at an api as being no different than a library such as jQuery, or a jQuery plugin. It has particular endpoints (methods), and he's asking how to get the existing methods to solve his problem. From that perspective, it's a valid question, but is lacking shown research.

Comment: @KevinB And [I did make the suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30036141/commissionable-sales?noredirect=1#comment48188242_30036141) to build an application layer to associate Orders with Employees, but what language should he build it in? How should he structure the schema? The question as it stands is too vague unless he's describing some difficulty he's experiencing in his own software design process.

Comment: Fair point, without knowing his application stack the only thing an answer can do is suggest a solution in the form of a concept or idea, it wouldn't be able to go much further than that. but, if that's all he's looking for..

Comment: @sjagr It *could* be answered by explaining what web API methods to call to accomplish what they want, assuming the answerer knows the API well enough to make sense of the rambling scenarios. It's better describe web APIs in terms of web requests/parameters, and let people determine how web requests are done in their language. Knowing the language they use isn't necessary to do that. I think the worse thing is he mentions several different approaches/scenarios in such a vague way it's hard for an answerer to conceptualize the problem and goal. Probably warrants "unclear what you're asking"

Comment: @sjagr Since you were wanting to be helpful, I think your comment suggesting a general approach is an appropriate response to such an open ended question, and asking them to be more specific was spot on.  Sometimes it helps to throw in "I'd like to make a suggestion to help your question get good responses.  You mentioned several approaches conceptually, and that is somewhat vague. Some concrete examples of an employee and order record might help." just to make it clear you are on their side.

Comment: IMO it seems like a bad idea to use SO as your official customer support.  Your answers can be edited by the community; moderators not employed by your company can close or delete questions; you can't provide any kind of "official employee" designation to people who are responding.

Comment: https://imgflip.com/i/l2ltj

Comment: I'm the original poster and appreciate knowing about this discussion. Reading the comments here gives me a better understanding of the issue and re-reading my deleted question without the context of the software for which it was asked does indeed make it seem very broad. I've undeleted and reworded it. As @KevinB suggested above, I only need a general idea, not a coding-specific example (which is one way it may seem broad to some). Once I know how Square can connect salespeople with sales, I can take it from there.

Comment: [I proposed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289157/reach-out-to-travis-ci-about-outsourcing-their-support-to-stack-overflow#comment171906_289157) a technical solution that would check the "referer" header when accessing the ask question page and display an additional warning if the page was linked from a non-SE site. At least that would warn the users *before* they get their question closed and get pointed to the relevant meta discussion.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The current consensus on Meta seems to be that:

> **But I was referred here by [company] for support!**
>
> Yes. For your on-topic, programming-related questions. For your
>   questions having specifically to do with writing code for their API.
>   For questions that involve customer service issues, you need to
>   contact the company directly.
>
> If the referring company did not give you clear guidance as to what
>   types of questions would be a good fit for Stack Overflow, [contact the
>   community team](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) and let them know; they might be able to reach out to
>   the company and help them establish better guidance to avoid confusion
>   for everyone.

That being said, I do not think that's sufficient. New users coming from company pages are going to be interested in getting quick solutions, they're not going to want to take the trouble that may, or may not, fix the underlying problem one or two months down the road.

The best guidelines I found for companies so far are here:

[Is it acceptable to use Stack Overflow as a Q&A for a specific product?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253849/is-it-acceptable-to-use-stack-overflow-as-a-qa-for-a-specific-product)

And as far as I can tell out of all the guidelines in the linked post above, it seems that Square doesn't seem to know about the following subset of guidelines:

> **Make sure we're not your only support option**

This is an important one. In fact, I would amend the rule to say:

*Make sure we're not your **primary** support option **to ask new questions***

Because while Square does list one other lesser support option on [its page](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/#implementationquestions). If you click on *"How can I receive answers to technical implementation questions?"*. StackOverflow is listed as the first option you should use to both read previous answers (which is fine), but also ask new questions for api-related questions (if not already listed).

> **Point bug reports and feature requests at bug trackers that you
>   maintain (not for the site)**

Currently, this is the [only second](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/#implementationquestions) option Square has:

> How can I provide feedback or feature requests for the Connect API?
>
> Please [contact support](https://squareup.com/help/contact) via email with your feedback or feature
>   request.

So not only, it lists StackOverflow as its primary support option to ask new questions, but it also doesn't specify a different place for submitting bug reports, and if you actually click on that link (which at first, I hoped was an email address, but is actually not), it takes you to a generic page for general customer support (where you can call a number, or email someone).

Obviously here, the first person you're going to reach is not going to be someone in QA or someone on the developer team, it's going to be a non-technical customer service person who may, or may not, even work directly for Square (but who may work out of some outsourced call center in Kansas or something).

Furthermore, Square has many millions of users, so it also means that if you contact them that way, the turnaround time may be super high simply because it's very hard to manage a customer service center that can handle hundreds of customer requests each day.

> **Make sure their question [is on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and not something [we'd prefer
>   folks not ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)**

Currently, Square [doesn't do](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/#implementationquestions) that.

It tells you what tag to use, but doesn't mention any of our rules.

> **Make it clear that Stack Overflow is a community run Q&A site for
>   programmers, and not a part of your organization.** It's important to
>   set people's expectations correctly when you send them over to us.

Square doesn't do [any of that](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/#implementationquestions) either. Following that advice would help a lot.

Now coming back to another astute comment from sjagr.

> I did notice that one user was consistently answering these questions,
>   and appears to be employed by Square. The answers he posted weren't
>   really answers, but full of helpdesk language (e.g. "we do/do not
>   support this feature").

I agree that boiler plate cut and paste help desk language is not something that we should encourage on StackOverflow. On one hand, I think that clearer language upstream would solve some of those issues. But on the other hand, I think we should encourage employee posters to avoid giving boiler plate responses from the perspective of the company only, and really go into why they won't really answer a question because the question is too broad (or because it's a duplicate, or whatever) in addition to whatever else they were going to say.

And yes, employee experts may not have enough rep to close a question. On one hand, that can easily be resolved by suggesting to companies that they only hire people with the required rep in the first place. But on the other hand, not having enough rep is not really a problem since they could just post a thoughtful comment instead (that someone else with enough rep could act on).

Now I realize that the team at StackOverflow would like to contact Square, and possibly offer them some kind of partnership (which is a good idea), where Square could rectify these issues, but also kick back a few dollars back to StackOverflow for the trouble (this is just my assumption of course, but it would be really bad if they didn't treat this problem as a potential opportunity for new partnerships and new revenue streams).

So while I agree with that approach, it's just that I don't think that approach is going to be fast enough, nor do I think that this approach will scale well enough in the long-run.

I believe that StackOverflow should post some clearer guidelines for companies that use StackOverflow in that way, and that it should collect direct employee contact information for the employees in charge of that part of their web site (they can list that requirement as part of the clearer guidelines SO publishes).

This way, SO could contact those people if those guidelines ever get updated (as undoubtedly, they will), and they could also contact them to see if they might be interested in some kind of partnership (or some kind of additional service SO could provide).

Also, I believe it should ask the companies linking to StackOverflow to give them a link to the page(s) they're linking from (with some kind of automated test, or manual checking of those pages containing those links)

In addition to that, I think that StackOverflow should provide companies some sort of web analytics for the traffic that comes from their particular site, or that uses a particular company api-related tag. This could serve as an incentive for them to keep their link and contact information up-to-date and perhaps it could help them optimize their FAQ.

And for the companies that don't comply, or that take too long to even reply, a large warning message could be placed on top of every page that comes from a particular referrer (or lacking a referrer -- those pages that are tagged with a particular api-related tag). This last suggestion would be an effective way to grab the attention of the company in question (while at the same time, providing some of the missing instructions/disclaimers to the new user who followed their link here).

Comment: This is great, and I read the whole thing since I burdened everyone else with my long-winded question. I really don't blame the user that made the question, and I don't blame Square either. I really think that StackOverflow has to take the biggest initiative to nip these kinds of things in the bud. Posting official guidelines which would be linked when a new tag is started, monitoring referring URLs for abnormally large trends from non-social sources (to catch backlinks to "question dumps"), and being proactive in the enforcement of the guidelines are paramount.

Comment: And yes meta posts are helpful, but not official, and certainly not as easily discovered. Without this direction, SO could become polluted with more of these "helpdesk" questions. Either way, I'm in complete agreement of this answer.

Comment: Yes, I agree completely. No one is to blame. Also, Square did a number of things right which I didn't list, which obviously shows that they're very much in tune with our community. And while I can't speak about other technical areas, in the area that I am the most familiar with, which is Android. Square has been one of the most generous companies (aside from Google) in terms of creating and supporting non-Square-related open source libraries for the entire Android developer community at large.

Comment: "I would expect them to mention the biggest ones at least, especially as they relate to their api-related questions" - I'll nitpick over that one.  It's not Square's responsibility to communicate SO's rules to anybody.  It makes no difference if they refer users to the site or not.  Making sure users understand the rules is SO's responsibility, and nobody else's.  If there's a problem with users coming in off the back of a third-party referral and not paying attention to the rules, the solution is to improve the messaging displayed to new users rather than to blame the third-party referrer.

Comment: @aroth, This is not a moral argument. There is no blame. If third parties are using SO as their support site, it's because SO has encouraged it with its previous messaging and its previous partnerships.  If you have a problem with that business model, you might want to start your own thread on that subject. Personally, I don't have a problem with it. I just think that we can improve upon it by improving the messaging displayed to third-party referrers, and if that doesn't work, then I'm suggesting that we adjust the messaging we display to the users coming from those third party referrers.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk - I didn't invoke morals?  I was nitpicking over the stated _expectation_ that Square inform people they refer to SO of SO's rules.  I don't believe there's reasonable grounds for expecting that of any third-party referrer (should Google/Yahoo/Bing also be expected to display SO's rules when they display a link to content on SO?).  And "blame" I meant in the context of "shoulder with the expectation/responsibility of preventing low-quality content".  I think that task falls squarely on the shoulders of SO, and no third-party referrer can be expected to take it up.

Comment: @aroth, I'm sorry. The wording I used could have been better. I'll go ahead and change it. And you're right about search engines. It's mostly StackOverflow molding itself to the search engines, not the other way around. However, in cases like Google announcing StackOverflow to be an official place of support for Android developers. http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/hello-stack-overflow.html This deal was actually negotiated between StackOverflow and Google. Both entered into a contract with each other. Both gave conditions to each other. And I see nothing wrong with that either.

Comment: @aroth "I was nitpicking over the stated expectation that Square inform people they refer to SO of SO's rules" - of course it's not their responsibility to explain all of SO's rules, but it _is_ their responsibility to clearly communicate what SO should and shouldn't be used for. SO has already dealt with many companies who didn't do so; e.g. [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261199/1110381). Search meta for "reach out to" for more of the same.

Comment: @l4mpi - SO can certainly reach out to third-parties and try to arrange better verbiage or broker a formal agreement, and that's great when the third-party plays along.  But I think it's inaccurate to say that they're obliged to play along, and wishful thinking to believe that SO can do anything if they don't.  As a public site with open registration, we have no _effective_ sanctions to use.  As a matter of practicality, user-education is our responsibility.  SO doesn't have the power to prevent anyone from saying "we don't run an internal support site, why don't you try SO instead?".

Comment: @aroth you missed my point - of course a third party can do whatever it wants, but the _expectation_ is that they act somewhat reasonable, and don't intend to piss off their own developer base as well as SO (and thus also respond to feedback by SO). As for "SO can't do anything": if a company were to tell people to ask questions under a specific company tag but most questions asked would be off topic, SO could simply blacklist the tag.

Comment: @aroth If people don't get the help they're looking for here because Square sent them here with improper/insufficient guidance (resulting in their questions being closed rather than answered), they're more likely to blame Square than they are to blame SO. Square is who they're trying to talk to, after all. SO can't *directly* force 3rd parties to follow our guidelines, but it can (and generally will) do considerable damage to their reputation for customer service if they *don't* follow the guidelines.

Comment: @l4mpi/ObliviousSage - I think we're just using different definitions of "responsible".  I don't dispute that it's in Square's own best interest to make sure that their users actually stand a good chance of finding help, or that they're primarily harming themselves if they don't.  Just the notion that there's an obligation for them to do so, or that because of that obligation SO's own responsibility to ensure that its new users are properly informed of what's expected of them, regardless of where they came in from, is somehow lessened.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I can tell, publicly consumable APIs are [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for SO:

> Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
>   … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

That said, [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [dont-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) both list restrictions to the questions that can/should be asked.  A quick survey of the [square-connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/square-connect) tagged questions showed 2 of the first 15 questions were off topic and should be closed.