# Should we do something about vendor redirecting questions to SO?

Tags: discussion

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30268798/docusign-sharepoint-2013-solution-will-not-install) where the OP says in a comment that he contacted DocuSign Customer Support and got this answer:

> Hello, Thank you for contacting DocuSign Customer Support. Kindly post
>   your concern about that issue on this site
>   stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docusignapi There are developers
>   that are willing to help you on that issue. Best Regards, Dan Gerard
>   B. DocuSign Customer Support

It doesn't seem right that they would tell their customers to posts questions in SO instead of helping them. Is there anything we can do about this? Should we do anything?

Comment: Recent related thread: [Square is using SO as their "tech support forum"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292309/square-is-using-so-as-their-tech-support-forum-lots-of-off-topic-questions-a)

Comment: I think the best that we can do is wait for someone on the Community Team to reach out to them with a letter about using Stack Overflow for their support system...

Comment: @Makoto - I see thanks. And just to make it clear, when we find post like that, the course of action is to post something here? or is there any other advised way to handle it?

Comment: Post it here.  I doubt flagging makes sense in this context (I wouldn't have personally used a flag, that is).

Comment: Good catch! Am I cynical in thinking that companies are trying to cut costs by trying to make us their tech support?

Comment: @santiago They are definitely trying to cut costs, but then the quality of customer support might be better than anything they could ever provide on their own.  Also, I like the idea of making people who want to actually help ("us") into tech support instead of clueless scripted robots who have never actually used the product.

Comment: @santiago - It looks like it, doesn't it?

Comment: @chappjc - I think the OP has always the option to post here. But for them to tell them to go to SO and ignore their customers... If they don't have support that actually knows about their product, it just speaks badly yet again of them. There are a lot of companies that have their own forums and user support sites and users and yet you would come to SO and ask, but that is our choice, not some company saving costs at our expense, heh

Comment: It would be interesting if some official from these companies would come here and state their case (mainly out of curiousity)

Comment: @chappjc oh yes, there is a definite learning opportunity for us - but these companies should at least have a link to how to post.

Comment: @santiago I was pointing out there is motivation beyond cost cutting for these companies (improved support). I agree that is not right to dump their customers here without instruction and an alternate tier of support.

Comment: @chappjc yes, I agree also that the support here would potentially be a step up.

Comment: Aren't some companies active in answering questions about their products here? Surely if they encourage users to post here, then post good answers, the company gets better a support knowledgeable, and SO gets more useful questions and answers, more visitors, and potentially more long term users - I think this should be allowed, although it shouldn't be an excuse for companies to just make their internal support crappy.

Comment: Google announced on  their Chrome extensions group that developers should start using SO for support. ref: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/chromium-extensions/cRSn0ys7Yb8/GZA1YqRelv4J (although I am quite sure everyone on that fprum  at least knows how to use SO).

Comment: Worth remembering that Microsoft [moved IE development support](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/8ba70824-dba2-4425-bc75-247c2c29bde1/ie-web-development-support-moving-to-stack-overflow?forum=iewebdevelopment) to StackOverflow too, and that was [discussed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277810/ie-web-development-support-moving-to-stack-overflow) at length.

Answer (score -2):

From my experience with [Wireshark QA](https://ask.wireshark.org/) and Unity3D's portal,

- if product's userbase is big
- if it's intended for general public use

Stackoverflow is just better than these attempts to make their own portal. More answers, and some portals (think `Perl` or `Android` tags) are quite big. And, I must note, here we have far less retarded mods and top poster than on closed-usage resources.

My opinion: custom QA portals  should be created only for private, paywalled areas. General questions go here. Language-localized versions have no right to exist too :)

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company While SO is good for programming questions, it should not be used for other questions, nor general support, nor should it be the only channel.

Comment: @Deduplicator its hard to tell when question goes out of "general support" scope and becomes "how to solve this corner case".. it would be cool to keep general support on local resources and move all integration/non-documented things here, maybe even on some schedule - no answers for day, move to SO..

Comment: @kagali-san - if you're not a developer with a programming question and get redirected here then that's wrong. That's what appears to be happening in this case.